# Select Multiple Issue Using Uniform JS

Tags: select, uniform

I am using **uniform.js** for my form element, all are working fine but I facing issue in **select multiple**. Only **select** is looking fine but when I am using **select multiple** that reflect like **select**. Please help me.

Comment: Hey... It is solved I am using jquery.uniform.js and remove jquery.uniform.min.js. Now it is working fine.